# Why are this all the invariant subspaces from the derivation on $\sin$ and $\cos$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

If we consider the function derivative $\phi:f(x)\to \frac{df(x)}{dx}$, over the linear space $V$ given by the spam from $\langle \cos x, \sin x,\dots \cos (nx), \sin (nx)\rangle$, I want to find all invariant subspaces $(\phi(W)\subseteq W)$, is easy to note that for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ the subspace $V_k=\langle \cos(kx),\sin(kx) \rangle$ is invariant under the derivative. And moreover $V=V_1 \oplus V_2 \oplus \dots \oplus V_n $. But how can I show that these are ALL the invariant subspaces? Can you give me some hint?

Comment: Note that any sum such as $V_1 \oplus V_3$ would also be an invariant subspace

Comment: You might be more used to dealing with invariant subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$. If so, consider the fact that the matrix representation is block diagonal with the blocks $\begin{pmatrix}0&n\\-n&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Count the dimension of the space to show that you got them all.

Comment: @Joppy Why the dimension on the spaces gives me that?

Comment: All those spaces are disjoint, so the sum of their dimensions should be the dimension of the space. There are more invariant subspaces actually, but made out of sums of those irreducible subspaces you’ve found: $V_1 \oplus V_2$ and so on.